# When click outside display none class element

Tags: javascript

The problem is that I don't know how to check with javascript: when I click outside of the div display none that class.

I have already tried to do it but doesn't work.

```
<section class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="more-text-1" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="more-text-1" class="lbl-toggle" tabindex="0"><script>document.write(lan[79]);</script></label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
       <div id="rightbox" style="float: right;background-color:white;border-radius: 20px;">
          </br>

          <div class="form-group" id="bukrsproject" style="float: left;">

          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="form-group" id="prctrproject" style="">

</div>
 <div class="form-group" id="posidproject" style="float: left;padding-top:15px;">

          </div>

          <div style="float: left;padding-left: 28px;   " >



          </div>

          </div>  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to do this: if I click outside of the div to change `display:none` to `class : collapsible-content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register a click listener at the `document` level that does just that:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.collapsible-content') || e.target.hasClass('.collapsible-content')) return;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-content')].forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none')
})
```

Inside the listener you check if the click was inside or on `collapsible-content`, and if so, just do nothing (aka `return`).

Otherwise, set all elements with `.collapsible-content` to `display: none;`.